# Grid not displaying all the rows

Tags: grid

Anybody knows why Grid only displays the first 100 rows.  I have a grid with 267 rows in control panel, but when I pulled the grid in my templates, it only shows 100 rows.  Does anybody knows why?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough Grid data to test this BUT it sounds very much like you are running into the 100 record limit that EE adds automatically to channel entries if you don't specifiy a limit.

Try setting a high value for the limit="" parameter, like 500 or so and see if that fixes it. It could be that without that parameter EE limits it to 100 automatically.

Comment: That's definitely it. I've seen that before. Without a limit param, a param of 100 is used on its own.  I've seen this with some third party loops as well, including matrix and playa.

Comment: Thanks @Jez Swinscoe. That was it. I've set the limit="300" and now the grid is displaying all the entries. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.